# Module over an algebra, what is it?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $A$ an algebra of the field $\mathbb F$. What is an $A-$module. I was thinking that $B$ is an $A-$module if

1) $A(+,\cdot ,*)$ is a $\mathbb F-$vector space

2) $*:B\times B\longrightarrow B$ is $A-$linear.

But it seems to be wrong, and I don't find the definition on internet (on google they only have module of rings).

Comment: It suffices to know that $A$ - as an algebra - is a ring. So an $A$-module is just a module over the ring $A$ as defined on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Module_%28mathematics%29).

Answer (score 1):

You look to make confusion with an algebra and a module (I think, but anyway, it's not very clear what you are asking). But I can try to answer : If $A$ is a ring, then a $A-$module is a groupe $(V,+)$ equipped with an action $A\times V\longrightarrow V$ s.t. $1_Av=v$, $(ab)v=a(bv)$, $a(v+w)=av+aw$ and $(a+b)v=av+bv$ for all $a,b\in A$ and all $v,w\in V$.

Let $A$ an $\mathbb F-$algebra. An $A-$module is now a vector space $V$ with an action $A\times V\longrightarrow V$ that has the previous property. So it's the same as an module over a rings with the particularity that $V$ is not a ring but a vector space.